# User.findOne() function throwing ',' expected error

Tags: mongodb, express, authentication

I'm making an express server that can be used for auth with MongoDB but this random error keeps popping up. I can't find the reason. Can anyone help me out?

Error:
',' expected.

This error is referring to the await User.findOne() command

Edit: The problem is resolved I wasn't using proper js object syntax. Thanks for the help

Here is the code

```
await User.findOne({req.body.email}).then(
        (log) => {
            if(log)
                return res.status(400).json({
                    msg: "User already exist"
                });
            else{
                const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
                user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);

                await user.send().then(
                    (log)=> res.status(200).json({
                        msg: "Registaration Succesfull",
                        log: log
                    })
                ). catch((err)=>res.send(400).json({
                    msg: "Registaration Failed",
                    log: err,
                }))
            }
        }
    ).catch((err)=>res.status(500).send(err))
```

Comment: just try `.findOne({email: req.body.email})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In object you need pass the name property, like this:

```
await User.findOne({email: req.body.email}).then(
```

Comment: Thanks, mate. I referred dev.to for the code and I used the same syntax which screwed me up. I'm kinda still learning backend development